# Python namespace packaging ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, module, namespaces, package, packaging

I am trying to have sub-namespaces inside of a module namespace.  (I'm trying to follow the documentation on [packaging namespace packages](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/#pkg-resources-style-namespace-packages))

```
project_1/
│       └── namespace
|           ├── __init__.py #declare_namespace
│           └── subnamespace
│               ├── __init__.py #declare_namespace
│               └── module_1
│                   ├── __init__.py
│                   └── __main__.py
└── setup.py

project_2/
│       └── namespace
|           ├── __init__.py #declare_namespace
│           └── subnamespace
│               ├── __init__.py #declare_namespace
│               └── module_2
│                   ├── __init__.py
│                   └── __main__.py
└── setup.py
```

Where my `setup.py` file in both `project_1` and `project_2` looks like:

```
#setup.py
setup(
    ...
    packages=find_packages(),
    namespace_packages=[namespace.subnamespace]
    ...
)
```

Also, the `__init__.py` modules where I declare a namespace look like:

```
#__init__.py
__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
```

Unfortunately, I receive a `moduleNotFoundError` when I try to run:

```
import namespace.subnamespace.module_1
```

Is it possible to have nested namespaces in python modules? Or is a namespace collision inevitable when I set up my projects in this way?